# How to convert gjf format to xyz format?

Tags: bash, sed, awk

The gjf format is as follows:

```
%chk=test.chk
# hf/3-21g geom=connectivity

Title Card Required

0 1
 C                  0.53424883    1.46721985   -0.02620215
 H                  0.89090326    0.45840985   -0.02620215
 H                  0.89092167    1.97161804    0.84744935
 H                  0.89092167    1.97161804   -0.89985366
 H                 -0.53575117    1.46723303   -0.02620215

 1 2 1.0 3 1.0 4 1.0 5 1.0
 2
 3
 4
 5
```

and xyz format is as follows:

```
5     # this is the number of atoms

 C                  0.53424883    1.46721985   -0.02620215
 H                  0.89090326    0.45840985   -0.02620215
 H                  0.89092167    1.97161804    0.84744935
 H                  0.89092167    1.97161804   -0.89985366
 H                 -0.53575117    1.46723303   -0.02620215
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick and dirty Awk refactoring.

```sh
#!/bin/sh 

for file_name in *.gjf; do
    awk '/[0-9]\.[0-9][0-9]/ { a[++n] = $0 }
      END { print n; print; 
        for(i=1; i<=n; ++i) print a[i] }' "$file_name" > "${file_name%.gjf}.xyz"
done
```

In very brief, we collect the matching lines into the array `a`, then print their number, an empty line, and the lines themselves.

This obviously requires you to have enough RAM to keep all lines in memory. If not, a temporary file is probably better (but your attempt could still benefit from some light refactoring).

Answer (score 0):

I wrote some thing like below and it works but it is almost stupid

```
#!/bin/bash 

 for file_name in *.gjf; do

 grep '[0-9]\.[0-9][0-9]' $file_name  | cat > tmp

 cp tmp tmp2 

 wc -l < tmp > ${file_name%.*}.xyz

 echo "" >> ${file_name%.*}.xyz

 cat tmp2 >> ${file_name%.*}.xyz

 rm tmp tmp2 

 done
```

Answer (score 0):

It is also good but not always!

```
#!/bin/bash

for file_name in *.gjf; do
tail -1 $file_name  > ${file_name%.*}.xyz
echo"" >> ${file_name%.*}.xyz
grep '[0-9]\.[0-9][0-9]' $file_name >> ${file_name%.*}.xyz
done
```